# Set contentresolver sort order to sort case-insensitively

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm making a contentresolver query to fetch all Songs. I'm setting the sort order to be `String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";`

The problem with this sort order is it returns all starting with capital letter first (from A-Z) then with small letters. I want to sort case-insensitively. Ex- I want the result to be like (A, a, B, b, E, f, H) instead of (A, B, E, H, a, b, f)

How can I achieve this in `contentResolver` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
```